# Summation of a list of pointers

Tags: c++, list

I am getting crazy by array of pointers .. 
If I have a list defined like this:

```
std::list<float*> total;
```

can anyone let me know how to add their elements to each other?

```
for(int i = 0; i < total.size(); i++)
{
     // add elements
}
```

It is somethig like array of pointers. I do not know how to sum them. I am newbie in c++ programming.

Editing:

Thanks for all your answers but since this pointers are pointing to Mat(opencv/image processing) seems does not work in my case :(

Comment: May I ask you why you are using pointers at all?

Comment: I expect you will get all kind of memory leak and dangling point later.

Comment: each one of these pointers are pointing to a Mat.

Comment: @hwlau: no, since I have declared the list in the class and I used pop_front to deallocate the memory.

Comment: It surprises me that you know how to write class, but you still don't how to dereference a simple pointer.

Comment: Do you have the option to use vectors? Vectors are (generally) preferred over "new blah[SIZE]", because of automatic memory management and extras like size awareness.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::list<float*> total;

float sum = 0.0f;
for ( float *p : total ) sum += *p;
```

Or

```
for ( list<float *>::size_type i = 0; i < total.size(); i++ ) sum += *total[i];
```

Or

```
float sum = std::accumulate( total.begin(), total.end(), 0.0f, 
                             []( float acc, float *value ) { return ( acc += *value ); } );
```

EDIT. The second example is invalid. lists have no the subscript operator. So I changed it to the following

```
for ( auto it = total.begin(); it != total.end(); ++it ) sum += **it;
```

Comment: I suggest the use of auto for newbie in your second example

Comment: @hwlau That would change the meaning. He doesn't use `auto` for iterators but for the "size type", which he initializes with a literal `0`, so it becomes `int` when writing `auto`. For newbies I suggest simply `int` in this case.

Comment: overlooked, I was thinking you are using iterator

Comment: Given that `std::list` has no `operator[]`, that loop is in any case borked. Even if it did work, instead of arguing over what type to use for an index, you could use iterators ;-)

Comment: Very nice answer. Just one remark: Using `+=` in the lambda is not really necessary, `return acc + *value;` would suffice.

Comment: @blackbird, You are right. The only preference of the record I used is that it is more vivid.:)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to **dereference** the pointers, using the `*` operator, when accessing the list, like so:

`*(total[i])`

However it is far easier to just store the items as a `std::list<float>` - STL containers stick their contents on the heap by default anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach is to use *iterators*: that way you don't need to do much refactoring if you change container type:

```
std::list<float*> total;
float sum = 0.0f;

for (std::list<float*>::const_iterator it = total.begin(); it != total.end(); ++it)
{
    sum += **it;
}
```

Note the double dereference: `*it` returns the *containee* (a `float*` in your case), so you need to dereference again to extract the actual `float`.

If you had a `std::list<float>` (which would be more normal) then you could have used an *accumulator* trivially.

**C++11**

C++11 adds new features that can be exploited here.

**1)** A redefining of `auto`. The compiler will define an appropriate type. You can write

```
for (auto it = total.begin(); it != total.end(); ++it)
```

which significantly reduces maintenance overhead.

**2)** for-ranges. If .begin() and .end() are well-defined then you can write

```
for (auto it : total)
```

Comment: I think that `for-ranged` loops are worth mentioning here.

Comment: ...or at least `auto`. I totally forgot how ugly iterator loops were ;)

Comment: Also you can trivially use `std::accumulate` even with pointers.

Comment: Good points: I've amended. I'm still supporting an old Sparc compiler so can't yet use all this nice stuff without lots of #ifdef ;-(

Answer (score 1):

```
float sum = 0f;
for(float* element : list)
{
    sum += *element; // for every element, add the value at the address pointed by the element.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::list` represents a (doubly-)linked list so you should use a range-based for loop (if you're compiling with c++11 support) or an iterator to loop through the elements.

As for your, every element is a pointer/reference to a float, so to access the value, you need to dereference the pointer. Here's an example with the range-based for loop construct:

```
float sum = 0;

for (float* element : total) {
    sum += *element;
}
```